# Select multiple rows including collapsed groups in the Telerik RadGrid for Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, selection, radgrid

Given is a Telerik RadGrid for Winforms at runtime, with multiple columns and some rows representing a group, of which some are collapsed and some are expanded. Groups can be nested. Dragging a rectangle over collapsed groups does not seem to work to select rows.

Is it possible to select these rows, collapsed and expanded, with the mouse at runtime by dragging a rectangle?
If so, how do I enable this feature?

Comment: I tried to create something that would solve your problem, but it seems in the latest version (Q2 2015) there are changes in how the mouse selection works, namely there is no selection rectangle. Can you, please, provide the version you are using so I could see what can be done to cover your case.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, we use Q3 2014.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mouse selection in RadGridView is handled in RowBehavior classes. The particular class you need is GridDataRowBehavior since selection is performed on data rows. So I have created a custom behavior class inheriting from the default behavior and executing some extra code after the default selection.

```
public class CustomGridDataRowBehavior : GridDataRowBehavior
{
    protected override bool ProcessMouseSelection(System.Drawing.Point mousePosition, GridCellElement currentCell)
    {
        bool result = base.ProcessMouseSelection(mousePosition, currentCell);

        if (result)
        {
            List<GridViewRowInfo> orderedRows = new List<GridViewRowInfo>();

            PrintGridTraverser traverser = new PrintGridTraverser(this.GridControl.MasterView);
            traverser.ProcessHiddenRows = true; 
            traverser.ProcessHierarchy = true;

            while (traverser.MoveNext())
            {
                orderedRows.Add(traverser.Current);
            }

            int minIndex = int.MaxValue;
            int maxIndex = int.MinValue;

            foreach (GridViewDataRowInfo selectedRow in this.GridControl.SelectedRows)
            {
                int rowIndex = orderedRows.IndexOf(selectedRow);

                if (rowIndex > maxIndex)
                {
                    maxIndex = rowIndex;
                }

                if (rowIndex < minIndex)
                {
                    minIndex = rowIndex;
                }
            }

            this.GridControl.ClearSelection();

            for (int i = minIndex; i <= maxIndex; i++)
            {
                if (!orderedRows[i].IsSelected)
                {
                    orderedRows[i].IsSelected = true;
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Now to use this behavior you need to unregister the default one and register this one. Here is how:

```
BaseGridBehavior behavior = this.radGridView1.GridBehavior as BaseGridBehavior;
behavior.UnregisterBehavior(typeof(GridViewDataRowInfo));
behavior.RegisterBehavior(typeof(GridViewDataRowInfo), new CustomGridDataRowBehavior());
```